# How can a government be legitimate?

Tags: law, constitution, government

In Myanmar, there are now two governments: (1) military government and (2) community representing government called ([National Unity Government - NUG](http://nugmyanmar.org)) formed from [Charter](https://crphmyanmar.org/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/Federal-Democracy-Charter-English.pdf) by Community Representing Pyidaungsu Hluttaw - [CRPH](https://crphmyanmar.org/).

In my opinion, I think that a government without constitution is just an organization, not a government. Currently, I feel like that NUG is just a shadow government and is working without constitution but with Charter.

Do you think that a government can be legitimate with Charter? It has been recognized by a few countries as a government and UN recognizes CRPH/NUG as representative of Myanmar.

Ethnic armed groups have draft of constitution for federal democracy for them - which was written for 10 years by all ethnic groups in Myanmar. But CRPH/NUG neither accepts or rejects as intrim constitution yet.

My question is : how can a government be legitimate?

Comment: A (written) constitution is a rather new development, Humans have governed for thousands of years without.

Comment: But we are in a new era, legitimacy usually is granted to a country with a constitution, or a common belief, that was written and is supported by the majority of people. Do you have the example of countries formed after WWII that without a written constitution or shared and announced common belief. IMO, the constitution or common belief is the cornerstone of a new country to getting started, democracy or not, but they can be violated later by coups or a civil war.

Comment: Governments have been around since human beings have formed groups or extended families in the form of clans. Most of them never had a written consitution: just a shared belief, common heritage, and a "system by which a state or community is controlled or regulated”

Answer (score 4):

In **some** political theories, the legitimacy of a government is created by the consent of the governed people. That's a core concept of democracy.

But while lip service to democracy is widespread, actual democracy is not a requirement for the acceptance of a government by the world community. Global institutions like the UN were developed at a time when not all countries were democratic and they have always contained non-democratic countries. The issue of dictating democracy to foreign countries raises another question, that of national sovereignty, and on balance there would be drawbacks if some coalition decided on [regime change](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regime_change#Foreign-imposed_regime_change) in Myanmar.

So it comes down to three points:

- Is the current government in Myanmar legitimate according to the current government of Myanmar? Yes.
- Will a new government in Myanmar be recognized if it overthrows the current government of Myanmar? Maybe.
- Is it morally permissible (or even morally imperative) for the people of Myanmar to overthrow their current government even if those actions violate the current laws? That decision must be left to the people of Myanmar.

Comment: “ Global institutions like the UN were developed at a time when not all countries were democratic and they have always contained non-democratic countries.” South Africa, 1994 (or around then)

Answer (score 2):

Legitimacy is a socio-psychological concept: a government is legitimate when and if it convinces a significant majority of its citizens that it is *in fact* legitimate, and they accept its laws, rulings, and judgments *as* legitimate. Note that 'legitimacy' in this sense is different from 'having power.' A government can rule over territory by force without the support or consent of its citizens. This often leads to insurrection, revolution, or interference by external forces seeking to take advantage of the government's lack of legitimacy, though a government may retain power for decades before those undercurrents reach critical levels.

Right now the military junta in Myanmar has power to rule, but a serious crisis of legitimacy. I don't know the reach of the National Unity Government; if they have significant enough support among the citizenry they have the potential to be legitimate, but they need to establish avenues of power in which they their actions can be *viewed* as legitimate. In other words, they need to more than a mere faction vying for power before the word 'legitimate' applies; they need to have political power within which their actions are deemed legitimate.

Comment: It is also important to note that legitimacy is subjective, and non-binary. E.g. the government of Taiwan is considered legitimate by its people but not by the government of China. And vice versa, the government of China is considered legitimate by (most of) its people, but not the government of Taiwan. And most of the rest of the world *officially recognizes* the Beijing government as the only legitimate government of Taiwan, but *pragmatically treats* the *Taipeh* government as the legitimate government of Taiwan.